# C++ Drogon framework model-based ORM

Tags: c++

I've began to learning C++ Drogon framework. I read the official and unofficial documents about the Drogon ORM. But I couldn't realized how can I create a model-based ORM database.

I want to create my models then run a migration command to map models to database tables.
If there is any document and guide about Drogon model-based ORM please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cpp
drogon::app().loadConfigFile("../config-name.json");
```

then run your sql command under [drogon plugins](https://drogon.docsforge.com/master/plugins/) after the program run. It's also will shutdown your custom plugin after the program exit.

It's require [config files](https://drogon.docsforge.com/master/configuration-file/), where you can add your plugin on `config-name.json`.

---

### steps:

**1. create plugins**

You can run from `drogon_ctl create plugin <[namespace::]class_name>` or create it manually.

Assume that your project root name is `MyProject` and says that your plugin `class_name` is *`my_plugin_01`*.

Do note that you also need to add both files to cmake add_executable.

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}  "main.h" "main.cc"

                                ...
                                "controllers/foo.h" "controllers/foo.cc"
                                "filters/bar.h" "filters/bar.cc"
                                ...
                                
                                "plugins/my_plugin_01.h" "plugins/my_plugin_01.cc")
```

**2. add your plugin name to drogon *loadConfigFile*, which is `config-name.json`**

```json
{
    "listeners": [
        // your list of addresses and ports
    ],
    ...
    // some of your config and so on
    ...
    "plugins": [
        {
            "name": "MyProject::plugins::my_plugin_01",
            "dependencies": [],
            "config":
            {

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**3. inside of my_plugin_01**

`my_plugin_01.h`

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <main.h>
#include <drogon/plugins/Plugin.h>


namespace MyProject
{
namespace plugins
{


class my_plugin_01 : public drogon::Plugin<my_plugin_01>
{
  public:
    my_plugin_01() {}
    // This method must be called by drogon to initialize and start the plugin.
    // It must be implemented by the user.
    virtual void initAndStart(const Json::Value &config) override;

    // This method must be called by drogon to shutdown the plugin.
    // It must be implemented by the user.
    virtual void shutdown() override;
};


} // namespace plugins
} // namespace MyProject
```

`my_plugin_01.cc`

```cpp
#include "my_plugin_01.h"

using namespace drogon;

void MyProject::plugins::my_plugin_01::initAndStart(const Json::Value &config)
{
    // Initialize and start the plugin
    // Do your sql logic.
    // Help: https://drogon.docsforge.com/master/database-general/database-dbclient/#execsqlasyncfuture

    // log to console when DEBUG is true
    if (MyProject::main::DEBUG)
    {
        std::cout << "\nPLUGIN INITIALIZE: my_plugin_01::initAndStart()\n\n";
    }
}

void MyProject::plugins::my_plugin_01::shutdown() 
{
    // Shutdown the plugin
    // Do your logic.

    // log to console when DEBUG is true
    if (MyProject::main::DEBUG)
    {
        std::cout << "\nPLUGIN SHUTDOWN: my_plugin_01::shutdown()\n\n";
    }
}
```

Each time `drogon::app().run();` your plugin/s will be initialze and terminate when program exit.

---

Another solution is use another framework/library from another programming language (e.g. dotnet, django and etc.)

You can do migration, create table and more from that framework/library.

This approach kinda neat but a bit complicated. Just be aware with your hardware resources.

*Do this if you want to extend your logic, where heavy/intense workload use c++ and when some logic can not be achieved with c++, use another one.*